# Solr/Lucene get the field in which the result is found

Tags: search, solr, lucene

When I query multiple fields for a string, is it possible to retrieve information in which field the query term was found ?

I want to query description, information, additional information ... But then I need to know which field gave the result As I want to give different layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene way: look at [`IndexSearcher.explain(...)`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html). This will give an `Explanation` that describes how `doc` scored against `query`.

Solr way: add `&debugQuery=true`. I queried for `collection:61` and got this document:

```
<doc>
  <str name="collection">61</str>
  ...other fields...
  <long name="uuid">1111</long>
</doc>
```

And then below comes this

```
<lst name="explain">
  <str name="1111">
     0.882217 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(collection:61 in 0), product of: 1.0 =
     tf(termFreq(collection:61)=1) 0.882217 = idf(docFreq=8, maxDocs=8) 1.0 =
     fieldNorm(field=collection, doc=0)
  </str>
  ...
 </lst>
```

Above basically tells that item 1111 had field `collection` with value `61`. You can also request for [`debug.explain.structured`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters) to get this explanation string in a more structured format.